# Window not opening inPyQT5 GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5, qvboxlayout

I am trying to create a GUI application using Pyqt5. The issue I am facing is that the code is running well but **record** window is not opening. I am attaching the whole code below and the snippet of the function which I am referring to. I have tried going through the whole code but haven't found any flaws in the same.

```
import sys
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
import time
#from libsonyapi.camera import Camera
#from libsonyapi.actions import Actions
#from pysony import SonyAPI, ControlPoint, common_header
#search = ControlPoint()
#cameras =  search.discover(1) 
#camera = SonyAPI(QX_ADDR=cameras[0])
 # create camera instance
#camerass = Camera()

###############################SECONDARY WINDOWS###############################################################################
        
class recording(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO START RECORDING #
        start_recording_button = QPushButton(" START RECORDING ")
        start_recording_button.clicked.connect(self.start_recording)
        layout.addWidget(start_recording_button)

        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO STOP RECORDING #
        stop_recording_button = QPushButton(" STOP RECORDING ")
        stop_recording_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_recording)
        layout.addWidget(stop_recording_button)
        
        self.show()
        
    def start_recording(self):
        camerass.do(Actions.startMovieRec)
        time.sleep(2)

    def stop_recording(self):
        camerass.do(Actions.stopMovieRec)
        time.sleep(2)
        
        
class zoom(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # THIS BUTTON IS USED AS ZOOM IN #
        zoom_in_button = QPushButton(" ZOOM IN ")
        zoom_in_button.clicked.connect(self.zoom_in)
        layout.addWidget(zoom_in_button)

        # THIS BUTTON IS USED AS ZOOM OUT #
        zoom_out_button = QPushButton(" ZOOM OUT ")
        zoom_out_button.clicked.connect(self.zoom_out)
        layout.addWidget(zoom_out_button)

        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO STOP THE ZOOM IN #
        stop_zoom_in_button = QPushButton(" STOP ZOOM IN ")
        stop_zoom_in_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_zoom_in)
        layout.addWidget(stop_zoom_in_button)
        
        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO STOP THE ZOOM OUT #
        stop_zoom_out_button = QPushButton(" STOP ZOOM OUT ")
        stop_zoom_out_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_zoom_out)
        layout.addWidget(stop_zoom_out_button)
        
        self.show()
        
    def zoom_in(self):
        camera.actZoom(param=["in", "start"])
        time.sleep(2)
    
    def zoom_out(self):
        camera.actZoom(param=["out", "start"])
        time.sleep(2)
    
    def stop_zoom_in(self):
        camera.actZoom(param=["in", "stop"])
        time.sleep(2)

    def stop_zoom_out(self):
        camera.actZoom(param=["out", "stop"])
        time.sleep(2)
################################MAIN WINDOW 1##################################################################################
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.windows = []

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        button1 = QPushButton("CAMERA CONTROLS")
        button1.clicked.connect(self.open_newWindow)
        l.addWidget(button1)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def open_newWindow(self):
        window = MainWindow2()
        self.windows.append(window)
        window.show()

###########################MAIN WINDOW 3########################################################################################
class MainWindow3(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.windows = []

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        zoom_controls_button = QPushButton("RECORDING")
        zoom_controls_button.clicked.connect(self.open_newWindow3)
        l.addWidget(zoom_controls_button)

        s = QWidget()
        s.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(s)

    def open_newWindow3(self):
        window = recording()
        self.windows.append(window)
        window.show()
        

################################MAIN WINDOW 2##################################################################################

class MainWindow2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.windows = []

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        zoom_controls_button = QPushButton("ZOOM CONTROLS")
        zoom_controls_button.clicked.connect(self.open_newWindow2)
        l.addWidget(zoom_controls_button)

        s = QWidget()
        s.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(s)

    def open_newWindow2(self):
        window = zoom()
        self.windows.append(window)
        window.show()



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

And the function is

```
class recording(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO START RECORDING #
        start_recording_button = QPushButton(" START RECORDING ")
        start_recording_button.clicked.connect(self.start_recording)
        layout.addWidget(start_recording_button)

        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO STOP RECORDING #
        stop_recording_button = QPushButton(" STOP RECORDING ")
        stop_recording_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_recording)
        layout.addWidget(stop_recording_button)
        
        self.show()
        
    def start_recording(self):
        camerass.do(Actions.startMovieRec)
        time.sleep(2)

    def stop_recording(self):
        camerass.do(Actions.stopMovieRec)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Why are you using `time.sleep`? Be aware that using blocking functions like that is considered a *terrible* practice in a GUI element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run it in my system and made a few changes. I am pasting the code below.

```
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
import time
#from libsonyapi.camera import Camera
#from libsonyapi.actions import Actions
#from pysony import SonyAPI, ControlPoint, common_header
#search = ControlPoint()
#cameras =  search.discover(1) 
#camera = SonyAPI(QX_ADDR=cameras[0])
 # create camera instance
#camerass = Camera()

###############################SECONDARY WINDOWS###############################################################################
        
class recording(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO START RECORDING #
        start_recording_button = QPushButton(" START RECORDING ")
        start_recording_button.clicked.connect(self.start_recording)
        layout.addWidget(start_recording_button)

        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO STOP RECORDING #
        stop_recording_button = QPushButton(" STOP RECORDING ")
        stop_recording_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_recording)
        layout.addWidget(stop_recording_button)
        
        self.show()
        
    def start_recording(self):
        camerass.do(Actions.startMovieRec)
        time.sleep(2)

    def stop_recording(self):
        camerass.do(Actions.stopMovieRec)
        time.sleep(2)
        
        
class zoom(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        # THIS BUTTON IS USED AS ZOOM IN #
        zoom_in_button = QPushButton(" ZOOM IN ")
        zoom_in_button.clicked.connect(self.zoom_in)
        layout.addWidget(zoom_in_button)

        # THIS BUTTON IS USED AS ZOOM OUT #
        zoom_out_button = QPushButton(" ZOOM OUT ")
        zoom_out_button.clicked.connect(self.zoom_out)
        layout.addWidget(zoom_out_button)

        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO STOP THE ZOOM IN #
        stop_zoom_in_button = QPushButton(" STOP ZOOM IN ")
        stop_zoom_in_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_zoom_in)
        layout.addWidget(stop_zoom_in_button)
        
        # THIS BUTTON IS USED TO STOP THE ZOOM OUT #
        stop_zoom_out_button = QPushButton(" STOP ZOOM OUT ")
        stop_zoom_out_button.clicked.connect(self.stop_zoom_out)
        layout.addWidget(stop_zoom_out_button)
        
        self.show()
        
    def zoom_in(self):
        camera.actZoom(param=["in", "start"])
        time.sleep(2)
    
    def zoom_out(self):
        camera.actZoom(param=["out", "start"])
        time.sleep(2)
    
    def stop_zoom_in(self):
        camera.actZoom(param=["in", "stop"])
        time.sleep(2)

    def stop_zoom_out(self):
        camera.actZoom(param=["out", "stop"])
        time.sleep(2)
################################MAIN WINDOW 1##################################################################################
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.windows = []

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        camera_controls_button = QPushButton("CAMERA CONTROLS")
        camera_controls_button.clicked.connect(self.open_newWindow)
        l.addWidget(camera_controls_button)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def open_newWindow(self):
        window = MainWindow2()
        self.windows.append(window)
        window.show()

################################MAIN WINDOW 2##################################################################################

class MainWindow2(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.windows = []

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        zoom_controls_button = QPushButton("ZOOM CONTROLS")
        zoom_controls_button.clicked.connect(self.open_newWindow2)
        l.addWidget(zoom_controls_button)
        record_controls_button = QPushButton("RECORDING")
        record_controls_button.clicked.connect(self.open_newWindow3)
        l.addWidget(record_controls_button)

        s = QWidget()
        s.setLayout(l)
        self.setCentralWidget(s)

    def open_newWindow2(self):
        window1 = zoom()
        self.windows.append(window1)
        window1.show()
        
    def open_newWindow3(self):
        window2 = recording()
        self.windows.append(window2)
        window2.show()
        
####################END#########################################################################################################
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you never create MainWindow3 where the recording class / window would be created after clicking the "RECORDING" button.

After creating MainWindow3 the recording window shows up after button press.
To test this you can just replace

```
w = MainWindow()
```

with

```
w = MainWindow3()
```

in your "main" (third last line)